# Existence of finite Borel measure $\mu$ with prescribed $\mu(X)$

Tags: measure-theory

while looking for another proof of the Riesz-Markov-Theorem I came to the following problem. Given a topological space $X$ and a real number $\alpha\geq0$, is there always a (finite) Borel measure $\mu$ on $X$ with $\mu(X)=\alpha$? For if not, what additional conditions have to be satisfied by X to guarantee the existence of such a measure?

Examples:

1. If $\alpha=0$, one can easily take $\mu=0$.
2. If $X$ is any bounded Borel set in $\mathbb R^N$ with positive volume, one can take $\mu=\frac{\alpha}{\lambda(X)}\lambda|_X$, where $\lambda|_X$ is the $N$-dimensional Lebesgue measure restricted to $X$.

Tanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\mu$ is a measure, then so is $\alpha \mu$ for any nonnegative constant $\alpha$.  So if you can find any nonzero finite measure, then you can find a finite measure with $\mu(X)$ being any desired value.  And this will be true as long as $X$ has at least one point (consider a Dirac mass).